# return the top 3 values of a count within each group using SQL

Tags: sql

I need a query to return the top 3 values of a count within each group - can I do that?

So if I currently used (made up example)

```
SELECT Client, Colour, COUNT(*)
FROM tblOrders
GROUP BY Client, Colour
ORDER BY Client, Colour, COUNT(*) DESC
```

to get

```
Client A|Green|275
Client A|Red|189
Client A|Blue|154
Client A|Purple|133
Client A|Black|14
Client B|Red|1025
Client B|Yellow|888
Client B|Blue|684
Client B|Brown|89
```

but I only want

```
Client A|Green|275
Client A|Red|189
Client A|Blue|154
Client B|Red|1025
Client B|Yellow|888
Client B|Blue|684
```

Comment: ah crap - first lesson then how to use boards formatting - apologies!

Comment: If you want to highest 5 counts, only group by count and limit the result to 5 rows.  How this is done is different depending on DB, which you did not indicate.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @dbug they want the top 3 per group not total.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this using the ANSI standard `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
SELECT Client, Colour, cnt
FROM (SELECT Client, Colour, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tblOrders o
      GROUP BY Client, Colour
     ) cc
WHERE seqnum <= 3
ORDER BY Client, Colour, cnt DESC;
```

Comment: Don't think MySQL supports ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: @DBug: you are right MySQL doesn't support [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) but there is no indication that Matt is using MySQL (and essentially every other DBMS does support them)

Comment: right, so until we see what the DBMS is, impossible to answer

Comment: @DBug . . . Answering question that has no database tags using ANSI-standard features supported by the vast majority of databases seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @Gordon, agree, wasn't criticizing answer, just pointing out it wasn't supported for mysql, if that was DBMS being used.  Since most do, then chances are that your solution would work.  That comment was directed more at OP to specify exactly what DBMS was being used.